# How to interpolate four colors?

Tags: java, android, colors

I need to interpolate four colors in my microphone visualizer.

- 1 color white if user silent.
- 2 color red if user says softly.
- 3
     color yellow if user says normally.
- 4 color green if user speaks
     loudly.

Im create Paint void for change color but i don't know how to interpolate this four colors, i know only how to do this with two colors. What i need to do?

```
 // used to take colors mix according to proportion
  private int interpolateColor(final int a, final int b,
                               final float proportion) {
    final float[] hsva = new float[3];
    final float[] hsvb = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(a, hsva);
    Color.colorToHSV(b, hsvb);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      hsvb[i] = interpolate(hsva[i], hsvb[i], proportion);
    }
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsvb);
  }

  private float interpolate(final float a, final float b,
                            final float proportion) {
    return (a + ((b - a) * proportion));
  }
```

Comment: There's more than one interpolation function that you could use, but what you probably want is: figure out between which 2 colors you're between, and only interpolate those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have already determined the current "volume" of the user in a float value where 0 is completely silent, and 1 is maximum, then I would do something like this:

```
float v = userVolume();

if (v < SOFT_CUTOFF)
    color = interpolateColor(SILENT_COLOR, SOFT_COLOR, v/SOFT_CUTOFF);
else if (v < NORMAL_CUTOFF)
    color = interpolateColor(SOFT_COLOR, NORMAL_COLOR, (v-SOFT_CUTOFF)/(NORMAL_CUTOFF-SOFT_CUTOFF));
else
    color = interpolateColor(NORMAL_COLOR, LOUD_COLOR, (v-NORMAL_CUTOFF)/(1-NORMAL_CUTOFF));
```

SOFT_CUTOFF and NORMAL_CUTOFF should be set to values between 0 and 1 that define at what ratio they should be the full color.